# Show a tabPanel in popup window or modalDialog

Tags: r, shiny

I need some help I want to show my reactive tabPanel in a popup with the `shinyBS` package.
Everything seems to work well except the creation of popup.
I am inspired by :

1)  [R Shiny - add tabPanel to tabsetPanel dynamically (with the use of renderUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470426/r-shiny-add-tabpanel-to-tabsetpanel-dynamically-with-the-use-of-renderui?noredirect=1&lq=1)

2)[Show dataTableOutput in modal in shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748316/show-datatableoutput-in-modal-in-shiny-app)

My code :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT) # need datatables package
library(shinyBS)

ui <-  shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("decision", label = "Choose your specie", 
                  choices = iris$Species, 
                  selected = "mtcars", multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mytabs')
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    nTabs = length(input$decision)
    # create tabPanel with datatable in it
    myTabs = lapply(seq_len(nTabs), function(i) {
      tabPanel(paste0("dataset_", input$decision[i]),
               tableOutput(paste0("datatable_",i))       
      )
    })

    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  })

  # create datatables in popup ?
  bsModal(
    id = "modalExample",
    "yb",
    observe(
      lapply(seq_len(length(input$decision)), function(i) {
        output[[paste0("datatable_",i)]] <- renderTable({
          as.data.frame(iris[iris$Species == input$decision[i], ])
        })
      })  
    ) 
  )
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bsModal` is an UI element, so you need to put it into you UI. Within this modal you want to show the `tabPanels` (rendered via `uiOutput`), so all you need to do is to place your `bsModal` into the UI, and within this `bsModal` you have your `uiOutput`. All what is left is to add an `actionButton` which shows the modal.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <-  shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("decision", label = "Choose your species", 
                  choices = unique(iris$Species), 
                  selected = unique(iris$Species), multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("show", "Show")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      bsModal("modalExample",
              "myTitle",
              "show",
              uiOutput('mytabs')
      )
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    nTabs <- length(input$decision)
    # create tabPanel with datatable in it
    myTabs <- lapply(seq_len(nTabs), function(i) {
      tabPanel(paste0("dataset_", input$decision[i]),
               tableOutput(paste0("datatable_",i))       
      )
    })

    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  })

  # create datatables in popup ?
  observe(
    lapply(seq_len(length(input$decision)), function(i) {
      output[[paste0("datatable_",i)]] <- renderTable({
        as.data.frame(iris[iris$Species == input$decision[i], ])
      })
    })  
  ) 

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for help exactly what I was looking for

Comment: One question please, is it possible to do the same with the `modaldialog/showmodal` functions ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you want to do (maybe @thothal has the right answer). What about this app ?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT) # need datatables package
library(shinyBS)

ui <-  shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("decision", label = "Choose your specie", 
                  choices = iris$Species, 
                  selected = "mtcars", multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("trigger_modal", "View modal")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("modal")
#      uiOutput('mytabs')
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # output$mytabs <- renderUI({
  #   nTabs = length(input$decision)
  #   # create tabPanel with datatable in it
  #   myTabs = lapply(seq_len(nTabs), function(i) {
  #     tabPanel(paste0("dataset_", input$decision[i]),
  #              tableOutput(paste0("datatable_",i))       
  #     )
  #   })
  #   
  #   do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  # })

  # create datatables in popup ?

  observe(
    lapply(seq_len(length(input$decision)), function(i) {
      output[[paste0("datatable_",i)]] <- renderTable({
        as.data.frame(iris[iris$Species == input$decision[i], ])
      })
    })  
  ) 

  output$modal <- renderUI({
    bsModal(
      id = "modalExample",
      "yb",
      trigger = "trigger_modal", 
      do.call(tagList, lapply(seq_along(input$decision), function(i){
        tableOutput(paste0("datatable_",i))
      }))
    )
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank for help @thothal reponse did the job :)